# В документе PDF не отображаются цвета

Tags: latex

Готовлю документ, в котором есть листинги программ и примеры выдачи. Хочу немного раскрасить это дело. Использую приёмы, которые раньше использовал много раз. Но в этом документе творится что-то странное!

Преамбула:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[usenames]{color,colortbl}
\usepackage[pdftex, unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[LGR,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{listings}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
```

Определяю цвета и раскрас листинга:

```
% Цвета
\definecolor{mygray}{rgb}{0.9, 0.9, 0.85}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}
\definecolor{lightYellow}{RGB}{0.9,0.9,0.4}  

\lstset{                                                                                                 
    language=SQL,
    keepspaces=true,
    extendedchars=\true,
    inputencoding=utf8,
    backgroundcolor=\color{lightYellow},
    breaklines=true
}
```

В теле документа пишу:

```
Для Windows:

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=tlBR, caption={Windows}]
sqlite3.exe tut.db
\end{lstlisting}

Для Linux:

\begin{lstlisting}[frame=tlBR, caption={Linux}]
./sqlite3 tut.db
\end{lstlisting}
```

И в сгенерированном документе вижу такую вот гадость:

[image: Это я вижу в документе]

tcolorbox тоже не раскрашивается. В чём может быть причина?

Comment: Не относится к вопросу, но... А Вы не хотите использовать шрифт Dejavu Sans Mono для листинга? - у него буква `el` хорошо отличается от 1 и от заглавной i. В современном латех этот шрифт уже есть и в нем есть кириллические символы.

Comment: @Vladimir - обязательно попробую, когда разберусь с проблемой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пакет `color` с каким-то пакетом (если точно, то с опцией `dvips` от `graphicx`) конфликтует, его (`color`) можно просто перенести ниже или убрать эту опцию.
И, как оказалось, виновато и само определение желтого цвета :-).

Вы случайно написали капсом название палитры, вот оно и мстит.

Вместо
`\definecolor{lightYellow}{RGB}{0.9,0.9,0.4}`

должно быть `\definecolor{lightYellow}{rgb}{0.9,0.9,0.4}`

и тогда все нормально компилируется и отображается.

PS: а еще, у Вас пакет hyperref два раза включен. Нижний лучше отключить, чтобы случайно не возникло конфликта опций пакета.

Comment: "можно просто перенести ниже" - Операторы *\usepackage[table]{xcolor}* и *\usepackage{tcolorbox}* перенёс в самый конец преамбулы и всё заработало!!! Вы не знаете, случайно, где можно бубен купить ?

Comment: @Sergey, лет 10 назад еще был сайт, где продавались игрушки пингвин Tux, чёртики от бсд и прочая атрибутика свободного софта... Вот там же были и бубны :-). Но ссылка куда-то затерялась (а скорее всего, и сам ресурс уже не поддерживается).